# Magento 1.9 login loop , no redirection to dashboard

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i have a Magento 1.9.1 stack, it was working fine but now when tried to login to the magento admin dash, It doens't offer an error like "Incorrect username or password", it just reloads the login page. And when I refresh the page i get the dashboard .

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recommented to comment following lines in:

> app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

```
/* to solve login issue */
/* if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
   unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
   if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
     unset($cookieParams['secure']);
      if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
        unset($cookieParams['domain']);
      }
    }
  }
   if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
     $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain(); //I have commented these lines
   } */
```

And for some older versions below was recommented in the same file.

```
$cookieParams = array(           
  'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),           
  'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),           
  //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain()           
  //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),           
  //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()       
);
```

Comment: Clearing the application storage from Chrome's DevTools fixed this issue for me.